# GET and POST in php7

Tags: php, forms

Just wondering, do `$_GET` and `$_POST` still work properly in php7? Or do they actually work in a different way than in the old one?
I try to make this code work in a way it returns param 2 when the page url reads `do = update` at some point, but it didn't. Can someone help me?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['do']) == "update") {
        $param=2;
    }
    else{
        $param=1;
    }
?>
```

I assume I am supposed to redirect to a certain page when $param=2 after this link is clicked

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?menu=user&user_id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>&do=update">Update</a>
```

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean, as it always has done...

Comment: `isset` used to test the data is set or not and you cannot use this `isset` with `==` operator and first check the $_GET is set or not then compare the value with update

Answer (score 4):

`$_GET` and `$_POST` still works. Your conditional doesn't, should be :

```
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'update') {
    $param = 2;
} else {
    $param = 1;
}
```

(as a fun note, can be simplified to):

```
$param = (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'update' ? 2 : 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

No there's no change to this functionality in PHP7. These variables are fundamental to interacting with HTTP, they can't really change unless that standard changes. Anyway it's nothing to do with that, you simply made a nonsensical comparison:

```
isset($_GET['do'])
```

will return either `true` or `false`. If it's `false` it will never be equal to the string "update". If it's `true` it might by equal by accident because you used `==` instead of `===`. But either way it makes no logical sense to try and compare them. It's not a useful comparison

This code is probably more like you were intending:

```
<?php
$do = $_GET['do'];

if(isset($do)) //only continue if the variable is definitely set
{ 
  if ($do == "update")
  {
    $param = 2;
  }
  else
  {
    $param = 1;
  }
}
else
{
 //do something else if the variable is not even set - perhaps an error?
}
?>
```

Or maybe you wanted to set $param = 1 in all cases except when "do" is set to "update". Your intent is not 100% clear, but the point is your that `if` statement is wrong.